# using a camera in android (and Parse)

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm using a camera on my app and I have two problems:
1. The app crashes sometimes when I click the save button after taking the picture.
2. I can't call Intent. I set a button on the layout (I deleted it) and when you click it, it should go to another activity, and it always crashes. 
Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode==0) 
    {
        if (resultCode==RESULT_OK)
        {
            bmp=(Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
            iv.setImageBitmap(bmp); 
            user.put("picureBMP", BitMapToString(bmp));
            user.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {

                @Override
                public void done(ParseException arg0) {
                    Intent intent=new Intent(CameraActivity.this,TeacherHomePageActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });

        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.imgTakePic:
            Intent TakePic=new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(TakePic,0);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }


}
```

Comment: Give us crash log, so we could help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
       protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,    Intent data) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if (requestCode==0) 
{
    if (resultCode==RESULT_OK)
    {
        bmp=(Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
        iv.setImageBitmap(bmp); 
   bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();

        // Create the ParseFile


      user.put("picureBMP",file);


        user.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {

            @Override
            public void done(ParseException arg0) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(CameraActivity.this,TeacherHomePageActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

    }
}
 }

   @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
   switch(v.getId())
   {
    case R.id.imgTakePic:
        Intent TakePic=new                        Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(TakePic,0);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

}

Comment: ok, but this is not my problem,Im saving the bit map as string and I can see the picture in another activity, I need a solution that will solve my problem of crashes

Comment: can you Post your logcat report